# How do I open a post in a custom page in wordpress?

Tags: theme-development, permalinks, pages

I'm new to coding wordpresst themes. I made a whale loop on the index.php page, by clicking on the link I want the post to open on another page.php. Do I need to change anything to Permalink or?

The example below is index.php, and the page.php (page.php example does not have an excerpt).

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo("charset"); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php bloginfo("name"); ?></title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). "/style.css" ?>">
    </head>
    
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="loop" class="loop" >
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div id="loop-con" class="loop-con">
         <div id="thm" >
         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?> </a> <?php endif; ?>
         </div>
         <div id="ex" >
             <div id="ext" ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
             <div id="exe" class="child7947810000"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
         </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else : echo '<p>No content found</p>'; endif; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

page.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
    <head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo("charset"); ?>">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title><?php bloginfo("name"); ?></title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). "/style.css" ?>">
    </head>
    
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="loop" class="loop" >
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <div id="loop-con" class="loop-con">
         <div id="thm" >
         <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?> </a> <?php endif; ?>
         </div>
         <div id="ex" >
             <div id="ext" ><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
         </div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; else : echo '<p>No content found</p>'; endif; ?>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Celso thx for editing. Please help I struggle with this all day. Do you have any idea why my page.php is not working. The permalink always returns to index.php after a click. As far as I understand page.php opens all posts, unless I type page-custom.php to open a certain different child page. Where am I wrong, why doesn't it work?

Comment: page.php is utilized for Pages.  If you want to edit your posts presentation you need to edit your single.php.

Comment: Ok that work. How i understood wordpress "searching" single.php for post, and page.php for page. Is this "searching" by default in wordpress? Can i change that wordpress "searching" post.php for posts?

Comment: @Maja Template hierarchy is an important WordPress concept that sometimes is not easy to grasp (and some uneven terminology doesn't help). Therefore, before going any further, I would suggest you take a look at the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) documentation and this visualization resource: https://wphierarchy.com/

Comment: Thanks, the hierarchy link is very useful, I understand now. I can't find it online, do I have to use index.php or instead  home.php or fron-page? Can I write a theme without index.php because it comes in 3rd place in the hierarchy?